# How to calculate speed of transitions between two event categories in column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, window

I have a pandas dataframe

|  | ID | api_timestamp | event_level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A9 | 2022-02-28 13:20:19.305 | NaN |
| 1 | A9 | 2022-02-28 13:20:21.703 | L1_1 |
| 2 | A9 | 2022-02-28 11:54:55.897 | L1_2 |
| 3 | A9 | 2022-02-28 12:18:00.882 | L1_3 |
| 4 | B1 | 2022-02-28 12:18:04.882 | L1_1 |
| 5 | B1 | 2022-02-28 12:18:05.882 | L1_6 |
| 6 | A9 | 2022-02-28 12:18:07.882 | L2_1 |
| 7 | A9 | 2022-02-28 12:18:08.882 | L1_8 |

Here I have events at two levels L1 eg: L1_1,L1_2  and L2

How to calculate number of L2 events between L1 event pairs for each ID

ie  Here for ID A9 , there is one L2_1 between  L1_3 and L1_8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is to sort the `api_timestamp` column and find the `L2` event between `L1` event by comparing the index of `L2` event and the max and min index of `L1` event.

```py
df['api_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['api_timestamp'])

for name, g in df.dropna(subset='event_level').sort_values('api_timestamp', ignore_index=True).groupby('ID'):
    l1_indices = g[g['event_level'].str[:2].eq('L1')].index.tolist()
    l2_indices = g[g['event_level'].str.startswith('L2')].index.tolist()
    l2_between = [l2 for l2 in l2_indices if l2 > min(l1_indices) and l2 < max(l1_indices)]
    print(name, len(l2_between))
```

```
A9 1
B1 0
```